# Emacs with JSON support

Tags: json, compile

I'm trying to compile emacs 28.2 (from `https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/`) with json support on a Ubuntu-based system (Linux Mint). But I don't get it to work meaning that `json-available-p` is void and I cannot use the `json-parse-string` function.

I installed the `libjansson-dev` library and added `--with-json` as a parameter to `configure`. It shows `Does Emacs use -ljansson?  yes`. But within emacs the json-support is not working. What else do I need or am I missing something?

Comment: @phils Ohh, yes! Thanks. I updated the problem ;-)

Comment: When you do `ldd \`which emacs\` | grep jans` does libjansson show up?  If not, you're going to have to recompile.

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, what happens when you do `(require 'json)` in your current emacs?

Comment: @g-gundam No, `ldd `which emacs` | grep jans` is empty. Not sure why since configure showing jansson to be used... Using `(require 'json)` does not complain and returns `json`.

Comment: How did you start Emacs. Are you sure that you are using the newly built Emacs?

Comment: Yeah, do `emacs --version` to make sure you're running the right one.  You can verify build settings with `emacs -nw -q --batch --eval '(message system-configuration-options)'` too.